# jasmine doesn’t continue executing the code in subscribe callback once unsubscribe is invoked

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

I've used these stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/dialog-example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-testing

and I've merged in this one:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-testing-r6bpfh

The example can be executed as in dialog-example stackblitz, setting TEST variable to false in main.ts, and so it can be checked that the expected behaviour is fullfilled: the dialogIsOpen variable is false after closing the dialog.

While testing I've mocked the dialog, so the afterClose event is fired inmediatly, but then the code beyond the unsubscribe call is not being executed. This can be checked changing the unsubscribe call and put after the `dialogIsOpen = false;` line. Then the line is executed, but not the rest of the function.

Is this a bug? Should I not to unsubscribe from the event?

Comment: What is your purpose for calling unsubscribe?  You do not have the unsubscribe in the first stackblitz example.

Comment: I want to avoid a memory leak

Comment: Then I would suggest limiting the observable, rather than calling unsubscribe where you have.  Something like `dialogRef.afterClosed().take(1).subscribe()` which will auto-unsubscribe after resolving once.

Comment: Thanks @dmcgrandle, this solves my problem: `dialogRef.afterClosed().pipe(take(1)).subscribe()` but, why the test fails?

Comment: Thank you, that is the current syntax with rxjs.  :)  I haven't tested your particular situation out myself, but my guess is that it is because you get a reference to the Subscribe, then as soon as it resolves you immediately unsubscribe, invalidating the rest of the resolve function.  With the take(1) you allow the first resolution to complete and THEN unsubscribe.

Comment: @dmcgrandle should unsubscribe invalidate the rest of the resolve function? I think this isn't documented anywere, and it's not the real behaviour, only testing with jasmine.